# ESP8266-01 NodeMCU read JSON in Lua

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

How do I receive and display the JSON data sent from a local server? I mean the script in the Lua fired at ESP8266 version 01. Ultimately, I want to display the data on an attached LCD 2x16 to ESP8266 by I2C.

I want to connect the ESP - 01 to a webapi server, which sends data, which contains different information, dynamically in JSON. I want this information to be displayed on the LCD connected to the ESP. I do not know how to decode the JSON data. The server address is `192.168.1.8:8057/api`.

OK. I try this:

```
sk=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0) 
sk:on("receive", function(sck, c) 
d = c
end )
sk:connect(8095,"192.168.1.8") 
sk:send("GET /api/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.8\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")

print(d)
```

and it display result:

```
{"lowVersion":1,"highVersion":3}
```

If I try:

```
sk=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0) 
sk:on("receive", function(sck, c) 
d = c
end )
sk:connect(8095,"192.168.1.8") 
sk:send("GET /api/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.8\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")

local t = cjson.decode(d) -- this is line 10
print(t.lowVersion)
```

is display:

```
test.lua:10: Expected value but found invalid token at character 1
```

How to display the value "lowVersion" or "highVersion" from JSON?

Comment: StackOverflow is about asking specific questions to a specific problem. Yours is way to broad. Do some research and ask specific questions when you're stuck. Which module do you use? There's no such thing as ESP8266-01. There's ESP-01 (only 2 pins) or the NodeMCU dev kit v1.0 - and [many more](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/).

Comment: Have a look here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules

Comment: Please, look again on my post. Please help.

Comment: Do you need any more feedback? If not please [close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

So, this whole question boils down to why your [`cjson.decode()`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/cjson/#cjsondecode) fails? It's because your server doesn't seem to return valid JSON.

Both of the following examples work just fine on a recent NodeMCU firmware from the `dev` branch.

```
local t = cjson.decode('{"lowVersion":1,"highVersion":3}')
print(t.lowVersion)

http.get("http://httpbin.org/get", nil, function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      local t = cjson.decode(data)
      for k,v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end
    end
  end)
```

Yields

```
1

args    table: 3fff0618
url http://httpbin.org/get
origin  xxx.71.91.xxx
headers table: 3fff0a88
```

So, your server doesn't seem to consistently return `{"lowVersion":1,"highVersion":3}` or it may return certain invisible but invalid characters.